# Having issue with commas during output for Oracle PLSQL function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Am currently working on a stored PL/SQL function FINDDEPENDENTS that finds the names of dependents of an employee by given employee’s number(e#). The function must then return a string of characters that contain all dependents’ names. All names of dependents must be separated by commas (,).

This is a fragment of the desired output:

```
00100 Albert: Bolt, Edee, Judy
00110 Alvin:
00120 Alice: Blures, Edee, Kadi
```

My current output:

```
SQL> select FINDDEPENDENTS(E#) from Employee;

FINDDEPENDENTS(E#)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00100 Albert:, Bolt, Edee, Judy
00101 Peter:
00103 Ami:
00105 Robert:
00107 Wendy:
00109 Michael:
00110 Alvin:
00120 Alice:, Blues, Edee, Kadi
00125 Angela:
00136 Aban:
00150 Bob:
00187 Eadger:
00200 Carl:, Eva
00250 Douglass:

14 rows selected.
```

My current code:

```
set echo on
set feedback on
set linesize 100
set pagesize 200
set serveroutput on
--
create or replace function FINDDEPENDENTS(empid in Employee.E#%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR IS
EID Employee.E#%TYPE;
Ename Employee.Name%TYPE;

DEPNAME Dependent.DName%TYPE;
finalRow VARCHAR(2000);
CURSOR q IS
--
select DName from Dependent WHERE E#=empid;
begin
select E#, Name INTO EID, Ename FROM Employee WHERE E#= empid;
finalRow:= EID || ' ' || Ename || ': ';
open q;
loop
fetch q into depname;
if q%notfound then exit;
end if;
finalRow:= finalRow || ', ' || DEPNAME;
end loop;
close q;
return(finalRow);
end FINDDEPENDENTS;
/
```

How can I edit the output so that there won't be a comma after :?

Answer (score 0):

There could be ways to manipulate the string with if else or trim or may be using regular expression to remove it but I would suggest to use `listagg` to concatenate the dependent names. i.e change the cursor `q` to,

```
CURSOR q IS
--
select listagg(DName,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DName) from Dependent WHERE E#=empid;
```

Or

I believe you must have some purpose to have a PL/SQL block but it also can be done with one query as something like which further can be used inside the PL/SQL code,

```
 SELECT e# || ' ' || NAME || ': ' || listagg(DName,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DName)
   INTO finalRow
   FROM   employee e
   LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT d ON e.e# = d.e#
   WHERE  e# = empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, if you don't want to update your function code is to use the `TRIM` function as follows:

```
select TRIM(',' FROM FINDDEPENDENTS(E#))  from Employee;
```